# what is the purpose of Id in drupal .info

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

In Drupal , what is `;$Id$`?

I know we use this in the .info file, which tells Drupal our module information.

My question is why is `;$Id$` necessary?

Answer (score 6):

$Id$ is the concurrent versions system (CVS) identification tag. If we want to share our module with others by checking it into Drupal’s contributed modules repository, this value will automatically be replaced by CVS.

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessary, but as Loveleen says, if you want to commit your module/theme to Drupal CVS repository and share it with the world, you must put the CVS Id tag in the first line of your php, javascript, css and .info files.

It must be written inside of a comment (the first line of the file), so depending of the file:

For PHP and Javascript files: `// $Id$`

For CSS files: `/* $Id$ */`

In the .info file the comment lines start with `;` so you must write `; $id$`

More info in the [Coding Standards](http://drupal.org/node/318#cvs) and [Header comment blocks](http://drupal.org/node/546)